# VBA - Dynamically Inserting a JPG at specific coordinates of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how to insert a picture file dynamically into a specific cell co-ordinates. I tried with this code but it is inserting the picture at absolute location.

```
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\zkumh45\Documents\StoryJPG.jpg")
                .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Left
                .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Top
                .Placement = 1
            End With
```

However, I recorded using a macro and this is what I got:

```
Sub Macro1() 
   Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 37.5
   Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 50.25
End Sub
```

This is what I have right now:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

The Red and purple texts are populated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can insert the picture to the defaulft position, then move it to suit your needs.  I'd encapsulate it in a Sub for conveniance

For example, if the aim is to position the picture so its top right corner aligns to the cells top left corner, you'd use this

```
Sub PlaceImage(rng As Range, Pic As String)
    Dim p As Picture

    Set p = rng.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(Pic)

    With p
        .Left = rng.Left - p.Width
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Placement = 1
    End With
End Sub

Sub Demo()
    PlaceImage ActiveCell, "C:\Users\zkumh45\Documents\StoryJPG.jpg"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way I could remove ALL pictures embedded in the worksheet in one go? One ring to nuke 'em all.

Comment: @ that would depend on a few things. Personally I'd just loop the Shapes collection,  test if the shape is a Picture,  and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of a good way to get things exactly where you want them to be but it will probably be good enough. I also don't have your exact image so you might need to do some tweaking.

```
Dim placerange as range
dim placeleft as long
dim placetop as long

set placerange = range("A2")
placeleft = (placerange.left + placerange.offset(0, 1).left) * .66 'Mess with this number, probably between .5 - .66 for that picture size
placetop = placerange.top

With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\zkumh45\Documents\StoryJPG.jpg")
    .left = placeleft
    .top = placetop
    .Placement = 1
End With
```

Comment: Will check this code out soon, but, at a quick glance, I do not want to increase the picture size. I hope the placeleft will manipulate where the picture is going to sit in the A2 cell?

Comment: Yeah, the size shouldn't be changing but the size of the picture will determine where exactly it falls. The top and left properties are what anchors it, so you might need to alter the placeleft variable to get your picture into the proper location. placeleft in that codeblock will place the left of the picture 2/3 of the way into the cell A2

Comment: Thanks, Warcupine for your reply. After running this code, I was able to place the picture on the sheet but for some reason the picture for the next row (see the purple row above, I have multiple such rows that get populated dynamically) is not lining up correctly.